# Question on IEC61010: Secondary circuit insulation requirement (creepage & clearance)

Tags: clearance, creepage

How does one decide if a particular isolation is required to meet creepage/clearance? Do all insulators have to conform to the creepage/clearance requirement?

In my design, I have a receiver circuit on the secondary side that takes in 1kV from an external source. At the front end, there is a protection circuit that cuts off the 1kV from the rest of the circuit, using power MOSFET and optocoupler. And then to relays and switches to switch the 1kV to different parts of the circuit before stepping it down. Do both the optocoupler and relay require to meet creepage/clearance?

My colleague mentioned to me that these need basic insulation, because if there is an fault, it could cause electrical shock to the user. The reasoning was that the external source is the accessible part and it is also considered an external circuit that the standard said we need to protect against. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific standard, but regardless you should do a risk assessment ("FMEA") to determine which hazards there are and what means that are necessary to reduce said hazards. Common sense will get you very far here - implement safety measures where you find that there's a risk to the operator/installer. Then you can refer to the risk assessment when claiming compliance. You can even be as detailed as specifying creepage/clearance distance in the risk assessment document, along with your reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Your product may fall in a different category, but start with EN IEC 60950-1 and take a look at the tables in EN 62368-1.

Creepage will depend on the CTI (comparative tracking index) of the materials used and the pollution degree. Many materials fall in material group II, CTI=400, but check with *your* PCB vendor (they range from 175 to 600 and look identical to the untrained eye) and the datasheets of the components used across your isolation barrier. Your average product falls in pollution degree 2. Hermetically sealed would be 1 and industrial would be 3. Special cases exists such as smelters and arc furnaces which can be 4 or above.

Clearance will depend on your working voltage and overvoltage category for regular mains powered products. For special cases, especially high voltage as your 1 kV input, you need to define your TIV (transient impulse voltage). From there, the maximum altitude will determine your clearance requirements.

There are online tools available such as http://creepage.com/.

Comment: Just a minor correction, with respect to frequency of encountering them: at least in my experience, FR-4 is most commonly in group IIIa (due to high organic content), or IIIb (unknown, by default). I see higher index materials exist, but haven't encountered them myself, or recall seeing them as options. So, they might not be regularly stocked by most fabs, but special-order materials. Everything else checks out; good answer.

Comment: @TimWilliams I’ll correct it when I’m at a computer again. Base material is usually 175 and solder resist 400.

Comment: Huh, I hadn't thought about CTI of mask; it's not usually even considered an insulator(!).

Comment: @TimWilliams From tracking standpoint, the soldermask is where the action is. Could be edge cases in pollution degree 1 where the PCB substate starts to track underneath the soldermask despite it will be free of pollution. But for a regular contaminated PCB surface but with high CTI of it, it will be the dimensioning factor.

Comment: Soldermask typically has pinholes in it, making it unreliable insulation (60950-1 *may* suggest an inspection-approval process could use it for that purpose; but does anyone actually offer that--?); tracking would be over its surface initially, but it's thin and I would think burns away quite quickly in the CTI test, not to mention the substrate heats up and chars all the same. *Shrug*, I'm not real sure of this level of detail myself, it's been a while since I read the standards in detail, and also CTI is kind of irrelevant functionally (if your circuit's arced over it's already toast!).

Comment: (it is of course a safety standard, not functional)