# IEC61010 applicability for non-measurement category rated circuit?

Tags: safety, isolation

I have measurement circuit that will be rated for CAT II 300V but do allow input voltage of over 300V up to 1kV. In IEC61010 6.7.3, "Insulation for secondary circuit derived from main circuits of overvoltage category II up to 300V", it seems to imply that only the circuit with working voltage <300V are required to follow the standard.

Is my understanding correct, that my clearance/creepage only need to meet 300V? And I don't need to apply 1kV clearance/creepage length since they are considered non-CAT rated?

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/697174/question-on-iec61010-secondary-circuit-insulation-requirement-creepage-clear